# unable to get out of the loop

Tags: java, applet, awt

Here's the while loop:

```
do {
    PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point b = a.getLocation();
    int nx = (int) b.getX();
    int ny = (int) b.getY();
    String sendMessage1 = nx + "\n";
    String sendMessage2 = ny + "\n";

    MouseEvent me = null;
    penOperationS(me,nxi-120,nyi-75,nx-120,ny-75);

    bw.write(sendMessage1);
    bw.write(sendMessage2);
    bw.flush();

}while(true);
```

In my code, control enters into this loop when the mouse is dragged(mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)). My problem is that the loop continues executing even if the mouse is released. I want to exit the loop when the mouse is released. What should i do for it?

Please help..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need a `break` statement

Comment: Change the condition of your `while` loop or add a `break` statement.

Comment: You could add a condition like this in your while : while(!mouseReleased)

Comment: I want the condition in which i can add the break statement..

Comment: @Gladhus, to do this, the mouseReleased should return any boolean variable. But, i can't do it. The error shows that we cannot return anything from mouseReleased() method..

Comment: @JayeshBabu, please check the answer below. In case that does not work for you, can you explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this instead, with `heldDown` being a member variable:

```
heldDown = true;
do {
...
} while (heldDown);
```

Then, in the mouse released event:

```
heldDown = false;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: It still not working.. I don't know what's the problem.. Is there any way to detect the release of mouse..?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([mouse is released])
    break;
```